# Possessive when both refer to a plural: "Hume's and Kant's moral systems" or "Hume and Kant's moral systems"?

Tags: grammar, american-english

Title says it all. What's the correct possessive to use when they both refer to the same noun?

"Hume's and Kant's moral systems" or "Hume and Kant's moral systems"?

Hume and Kant both have one moral system.

Comment: If there's one moral system, it's *"Hume and Kant's"*. If there are two moral systems, they're *"Hume's and Kant's"*.

Comment: I think it would be clearer if you'd said *Hume and Kant have one moral system **each*** (I assume that's what you mean, that there are two different moral systems involved).

Comment: Title does not say it all. If this is intended to be philosophy, questions of grammar are far subordinate to questions of clarity, and neither formulation is clear. Conjunction reduction (deleting the first _moral system_ after _Hume's_) is applicable only with certain presuppositions, which lead to ambiguity. This is generally taken to be a no-no in philosophical writing. Thus, _Hume's moral system and Kant's moral system,_ which may be one and the same, for all I know, can be amended to say "are identical", but it gives them distinct identities from the start.

Comment: Whilst I'm absolutely with John Lawler on this, I would add that the only time I would write Hume and Kant's is where they were the joint authors of a book e.g. Marchant and Sidebotham's *Fly Fishing for Beginners*

Comment: Got it, thanks. @JohnLawler, I apologize if my question body was ignorant of the actual reality of it. I'll try to be more clear (heh) in the future. Thank you all for your help on this question.

Comment: +1 for @JohnLawler. To clearly distinguish which meaning is intended (they have the same or different moral systems), you can say *The moral system of Hume and Kant* or *The moral systems of Hume and Kant*. In other words, to be clear, do it froggie-style (speak French). ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Given that Hume and Kant have rather different moral systems, it seems safe to conclude that the OP's sentence "Hume and Kant both have one moral system" means "Hume and Kant have one moral system each," as FumbleFingers does in a comment above.

That being the case, I endorse Peter Shor's sensible advice (offered in a second comment above):

> If there are two moral systems, they're "Hume's and Kant's"

The important thing here is to avoid the impression that Hume and Kant have collaborated on the moral systems under discussion and now share credit for elucidating them. This, I believe, is the upshot of WS2's advice (in yet another comment above) that it would be appropriate to say "Hume and Kant's" only if they had co-authors' rights to an idea (or moral system).